# How Can I Send Bulk Email by using Mailchimp with Oracle Apex?

Tags: oracle-apex, mailchimp

I'm looking to integrate mailchimp with my Oracle Apex app. Although I'm not sure how to do it, any ideas? There is not much documentation about that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Mailchimp has a number of API's to integrate with (https://mailchimp.com/developer). From within pl/sql you can invoke rest requests using the `apex_web_service.make_rest_request` api. There will be some config challences (ACL in the database, the oracle wallet for https connections) but once you've got those sorted this should be possible.